# list assignment index out of range codesignal

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to relax on CodeSignal but i got this

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  main.py3
 in the pre-written template, in getUserOutputs
    userOutput = _runjpmds(testInputs[i])
  main.py3
 in the pre-written template, in _runjpmds
    return almostIncreasingSequence(*_fArgs_fnlehdkfpkip)
  main.py3
 on line 13, in almostIncreasingSequence
    del(newarr[i])
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

But why?

```
def ifgood(arr):
for i in range(0, len(arr)-1):
    if arr[i+1] - arr[i] <= 0:
        return False
return True

def almostIncreasingSequence(sequence):
    if len(sequence) == 1:
        return True
    for i in range(0, len(sequence)):
        newarr = sequence
        del(newarr[i])
        if ifgood(newarr) == True:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: `newarr = sequence` This doesn't do what you think.  It does not create a new copy of `sequence`.

Comment: so what should i do instead? what does it do?

Comment: It makes the `newarr` variable point to the same list in memory as `sequence` - so when you `del` an item from `newarr`, that affects `sequence` too. To make a copy, try `newarr = sequence[:]` or `newarr = sequence.copy()`

Comment: Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list

Comment: Yeah, thanks, that worked